# Installing SciPy on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have Python 2.7 running and trying to install scipy by using easy_install which returns following errors:

```
Searching for scipy
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/
Reading http://www.scipy.org
Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=27747&package_id=19531
Reading http://new.scipy.org/Wiki/Download
Best match: scipy 0.11.0
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.11.0.zip#md5=40b700ddde9ddab643b640fff7a9d753
Processing scipy-0.11.0.zip
Running scipy-0.11.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-49BQSz/scipy-0.11.0/egg-dist-tmp-KMjwKy
Running from scipy source directory.
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1425: UserWarning: 
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1434: UserWarning: 
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1437: UserWarning: 
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
error: 
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
```

So I installed Blas and Atalas by executing

```
apt-get install blas
apt-get install atlas
```

However, the easy_install errors don't disappear.

Thanks!

Comment: do you try? "sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy"

Comment: I installed SciPy on my Mac with the Python Package Installer and don't remember having any trouble. Any particular reason you can't try installing pip (I think easy_install pip works), and working from there?

Comment: Using apt-get install scipy I get:
E: Couldn't find package python-numpy

Comment: Using pip I get the similar blas related errors

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ubuntu puts library files in a rather exotic directory.
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` or something, depending on your architecture.
You need to add this directory to the site.cfg file or the BLAS environment variable.

If easy install also needs the header files, you need to install the respective -dev packages.

But, like @pitsanu-swangpheaw suggests, you can also install to the site packages directory using the ubuntu package manager.

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy
```

Comment: As mentioned above for some reason apt-get doesn't find python-numpy. I get "E: Couldn't find package python-numpy"

Comment: It is in the [universe repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu), perhaps you need to enable that in your sources list. Otherwise, it may be an issue with your package index, which you can update using `apt-get update`. What version of ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 74):

What worked for me:

To actually install scipy from PIP, you need packages `libatlas-base-dev` (libraries etc. for ATLAS/BLAS) and `gfortran` (GNU Fortran compiler).

Once these packages are installed, the scipy installer should finish as expected.

Comment: Although the OP asked about Ubuntu, this also happens to work on Raspbian for the Raspberry Pi

Comment: The above are ubuntu packages (not python), i.e. use sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev

Answer (score 5):

`sudo apt-get install python-scipy` worked in my case.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Python3, You can install packages using `apt-get`

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy python3-scipy
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to still install using `pip`, you can use build-dep to get the dependencies of python-numpy and python-scipy, and then install using `pip`

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-numpy python-scipy
```

Substitute for python3 as the other answers state of that's what you're looking for.

Comment: very useful to avoid having to remember the particular packages that need to be installed (as suggested above)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by running (similar to previous suggestions)

```
apt-get install scipy
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem with running:

```
sudo pip install scipy
```